# How do I simulate multivariate non-normal time series data from existing dataset in r?

Tags: r, time-series, simulation

I’m trying to simulate data from an existing non-multivariate normal time series. The parameters:

1. I need to simulate both continuous and binary variables
2. I want the simulated data to have the same distributional properties (mean, sd, skew, kurtosis) and covariance structure as the existing data set
3. I want the simulated data to be on the same scale as the original data set
4. I want to be able to simulate a greater number of observations that what exist in the original data set

The existing data set is ~100 observations of 18 variables (1 binary,17 continuous 0-100 scale) assessed 8 times per day for 15 days. Most approaches I've tried in r either require the assumption of multivariate normality (which these data violate) or cannot handle binary variables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of "non-multivariate normal" would you mean "multivariate non-normal"?  Regardless, could you please explain the intended purpose of this simulation?

Comment: Thank you for asking: Yes, it is more grammatically clear to say that the data are multivariate non-normal. The purpose of the simulation is to extrapolate from the original time series with the hope of being able to simulate different model fitting procedures. I am aware that there are some concerns about the appropriateness of simulation for this purpose, but it is still something we are interesting in pursing (especially given that we have hold out data to validate our modeling approaches)

Comment: Any extrapolation is a model.  It sounds like you would be best served by first fitting a suitable multivariate time series model to your data.  Only then could you have any reasonable hope that the simulation would be relevant.